# C# Multi-dimensional arrays lengt

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
 string[,] array = new string[5, 24];
```

I want to get the length/size of the first array = "5".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`5` is the length of the `0`th dimension. [`GetLength()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength) will give you the result - you just have to pass the dimension

```
string[,] array = new string[5, 24];
int result = array.GetLength(0); //5
```